# Gravitational wave of Big bang?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, astrophysics, big-bang, gravitational-waves

Questions about the g-wave caused by the big bang:
1)was there a g-wave produced?
2) when will it reach us?
3) will it be too weak for us to detect(atleast now?)?

Comment: It would be nice to show you have put a bit of effort in this. For example [this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave+big+bang) finds a couple of related questions: [The gravity waves from the big bang? How can we know?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104731/) and [Is it possible that there are still gravitational waves of the big bang?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235495/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Note that a g-wave is not a gravitational wave, it is a gravity wave (note the same thing).

Comment: also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237418/what-are-the-implications-of-the-ligo-results-in-reference-to-our-current-cosmol/237440#237440

Comment: What's a gravity wave?@RobJeffries

Answer (score 2):

As the universe itself was created by the event, it's like asking when the shockwave will hit the center of the nuke's fireball. However, remnant waves were supposed to have affected cosmic background, and very possibly contributed to the large scale clustering structure of the universe. These "fingerprints" were [claimed](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/gravity-waves-cmb-b-mode-polarization/) to have been found, but it turned out it was [just dust](http://www.nature.com/news/gravitational-waves-discovery-now-officially-dead-1.16830).

I'm not sure how much research is being done about this, but it could be that omnipresent "standing" waves of extremely low amplitude and long wavelength are permeating the universe still.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not directly by the big bang itself, but in the early universe
   for sure processes were taking place which led to gravitational
   waves, most prominent the cosmic inflation.
2. They reach us all the time, same as the microwave background does.
3. Too weak for direct observation, but observation by their impact on the CMB seems in range.